# Recording the invoker of a Postgres function that is set to SECURITY DEFINER

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way for a function in Postgres (using 9.4) to find out the user that invoked it if the function is set to `SECURITY DEFINER`?

The design problem that I have is that I want to do user authentication via my web app (so that I can share a connection pool) but still maintain audit records within the database that reference the authenticated end user from the web app.

The current flow is:

- Users connect to a web app, and it does the authentication to verify that they are who they say they are.
- The web app then connects to Postgres via an app user.
- When any queries are executed on behalf of a user, the web app runs a `SET ROLE [username]`, then the relevant query, then a `RESET ROLE` before returning the connection to the connection pool.
- All user queries are done via functions. The users have privileges to run the functions but do not have privileges to make changes to tables directly (the web app account has no permissions except for the permission to impersonate certain users). The functions also maintain columns for concepts like "created by", "last updated", etc. by inserting/updating the appropriate values with `CURRENT_USER` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

The problem that I'm running into is that the `CURRENT_USER` always returns the function owner, and `SESSION_USER` always returns the web app account, whereas what I really want is the name of the account that invoked the function.

Is this possible? I'm not seeing anything particularly promising in the documentation. Conversely, how have other people solved this design problem?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that'll do what you want right now. You might have to write a hook function in C that wraps function invocation.

Answer (score 9):

You can define a [`DOMAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createdomain.html) which constrains `NAME` values to `CURRENT_USER`:

```
CREATE DOMAIN whoami AS NAME
CHECK( VALUE = CURRENT_USER )
;
```

then apply this `DOMAIN` to a parameter of your function. The parameter can be defined as optional, with a default value of `CURRENT_USER` (the default value is computed in the context of the caller):

```
CREATE FUNCTION restricted_area( caller whoami DEFAULT CURRENT_USER )
RETURNS TABLE ( caller NAME, owner NAME )
SECURITY DEFINER
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $SQL$
  SELECT caller, CURRENT_USER;
$SQL$
;

CREATE ROLE restricted_area_owner;
ALTER FUNCTION restricted_area( whoami )
OWNER TO restricted_area_owner
;

CREATE ROLE web_user;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION restricted_area( whoami )
TO web_user
;

SET ROLE web_user;
SELECT *
FROM restricted_area()
;
```

which gives the expected result:

```
  caller  |         owner         
----------+-----------------------
 web_user | restricted_area_owner
(1 row)
```

the `CURRENT_USER` can be also be provided explicitly:

```
SELECT *
FROM restricted_area('web_user')

  caller  |         owner         
----------+-----------------------
 web_user | restricted_area_owner
(1 row)
```

but no other value is accepted:

```
SELECT *
FROM restricted_area('postgres')
;

ERROR:  value for domain whoami violates check constraint "whoami_check"
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you.

Comment: This is so cool. Using a new domain is inspired and being able to operate as a privledged user while being able to audit who is invoking the function call is super useful.

Answer (score 0):

Every connection to your database is in the context of a session. Every connection in the pool has a session associated with it. According to how you describe your business logic, whenever you use a connection from the pool it is for a single user of your app. What you could do is to create a temporary table - which lives as long as the session does - and store the user details there for retrieval whenever you need it.

So whenever you get a connection from the pool, execute these commands (maybe the connection is new so the table might not exists initially):

```
CREATE TEMP UNLOGGED TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_details(
  -- whatever details you need
);
DELETE FROM user_details; -- previous session data, if any
INSERT INTO user_details VALUES (...);
```

You can also wrap that into a function and call that instead.

Then during your session you simply include table `user_details` in your `FROM` clause of queries or directly in your function body and pull the desired information out.